# Worst Case Runtime of Naive Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am not sure how to calculate the worst case runtime of an algorithm. I am familiar with asymptotic notation, but not sure on how to use it. One example for explaining could be :

```
d = (X1 - X2)^2 + (Y1 - Y2)^2
for i=1 to N-1 do:
  for j=i+1 to n do:
     t = (Xi - Xj)^2 + (Yi - Yj)^2
     if (t < d) then d = t
return d
```

This has inputs of a set of N points (X1,Y1)....(XN,YN) with N>=2 . Output should be the squared distance of the closest pair of points. How do i calculate the runtime of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm takes all possible pairs from the *N* inputs. There are *n(n-1)/2* such pairs, which is the number of times the inner part of the inner loop is executed. Assuming that the arithmetic operations are constant in time, the time complexity is thus *O(n²)*.

Note that there is no unknown factor in this algorithm that influences the time complexity, so this is both the best & worst case time complexity: *θ(n²)*